# Host is unresolved: api.twitter.com:80

Tags: java, android, exception, twitter, twitter4j

I am getting this Error while executing my android application :

```
Host is unresolved: api.twitter.com:80
Relevant discussions can be on the Internet at:
http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=10f5ada3 or
http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=dceba048
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[10f5ada3-dceba048 10f5ada3-dceba01e], statusCode=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, featureSpecificRateLimitStatus=null, version=2.2.5}
```

Though i have already set proper permissions.. here is my code :

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.abc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <activity
            android:label="test1"
            android:name=".A1Activity" 
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                           <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                           <data android:scheme="twitterapp" android:host="callback" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

     <activity class=".screen2" android:label="test2" android:name=".screen2">
      </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Code for my file is :

```
public class A1Activity extends Activity {

         private static final String PREF_ACCESS_TOKEN = "accessToken"; // Called when the activity is first created.      
         private static final String PREF_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = "accessTokenSecret";// Name to store the users access token secret   
         public final static String CONSUMER_KEY = "abc"; // "your key here";
         public final static String CONSUMER_SECRET = "def"; // "your secret key here";     
         private static final String CALLBACK_URL = "twitterapp://callback";// The url that Twitter will redirect to after a user log
         private SharedPreferences mPrefs;     // Preferences to store a logged in users credentials 
         private Twitter mTwitter;// = new TwitterFactory().getInstance(); 
         private RequestToken mReqToken;/** The request token signifies the unique ID of the request you are sending to twitter  */
         public int returnFlag=0;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

                mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("twitterPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);            
                mTwitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();       
                mTwitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
                Button mLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
                mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        System.out.println("1");
                        loginNewUser();
                        System.out.println("7.saveAccessToken ");
                        //Intent screenEnterZip = new Intent(A1Activity.this, screen2.class);
                        //startActivity(screenEnterZip);// Perform action on click                
                        }
                    });
                }


        public void loginNewUser() {        
            try { 
                    System.out.println("2");
                    mReqToken = mTwitter.getOAuthRequestToken(CALLBACK_URL);
                    System.out.println("2.1");
                    WebView twitterSite = new WebView(this);
                    System.out.println("2.2");
                    twitterSite.loadUrl(mReqToken.getAuthenticationURL());
                    System.out.println("2.3");
                    setContentView(twitterSite);                
                    //Status status = mTwitter.updateStatus("My First Tweet ... ");                
                    //System.out.println("Successfully updated the status to [" + status.getText() + "].");                
                    System.out.println("1. loginNewUser Completes ");
                }
            catch (TwitterException e) {
                System.out.println("ExceptioniZ "+e);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Twitter Login error, try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

The app opens in emulator with a screen showing a login button. But on login button click it is throwing regular errors now while the app was working few hours ago...
Can anyone suggest what could have been the problem .. ?

Comment: I just found out Android emulator has missing 3G icon.. what to do for that?

Comment: Its for probably for showing that you have a 3G (high speed) connection.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do it with android. Can you ping "api.twitter.com" ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598817/java-lang-runtimeexception-java-net-unknownhostexception-host-is-unresolved This person says to check the emulator...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably don't have an internet connection in your emulator.

Open up a browser within the emulator and enter "http://api.twitter.com". This probably won't work. Do the same on your local pc it should work there.

Comment: Yeah but it was there few hours ago.. how did it go..and how can i fix it Udo

Comment: Twitter has been very unstable today, so that might be it.

Comment: i just had the same problem. it worked, i left, came back, it didnt work. closing the emulator and relaunching fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, I got this exception because of my device didn't connected with internet. When I connect my device with internet everything works as expected.